# How to test this method J2EE webservice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have an Entity class in my webservice project called customers which is a JPA entity from a database table that has attributes that describe a customer like username, password etc.

I have a webservice called customermanagement that basically handles crud operations for customers.

For example the createcustomer method is something like :

```
public void createcustomer(customers customer)
{
  em.persist(customer)

}
```

Now the issue is, at the client side i have the methods of this webservices but don't know how to pass the object parameter of customers.

```
public boolean CreateUser()
{
    this.username = "John";
    this.fullname = "Doe";
    this.password = "magic";

    webservice.createcustomer() #this has to take an object instead. So how may i do it ?
}
```

Excuse my skill level. I am not so familiar with Object Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create object of entity class like this:

```
Customers customer = new Customers("John", "Doe", "Magic");
```

and pass the Customer object to your method:

```
webservice.createcustomer(customer);
```

There is shorter way to do that:

```
webservice.createcustomer(new Customers("John", "Doe", "Magic"));
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Do you think it's a good practice to follow this paradigm ? I mean since it's a webservice which i am offering to someone it means i may have to also provide to them the customer class ? since without it they can't create the object.